# JQuery Pipe Method - How to pass multiple parameters?

Tags: jquery, deferred

I am trying to use jQuery's deferred functionality.  What I want to do is call a GetToken function (which validates username and password and returns a token), then call another function, passing the token in as the first parameter... and then several other parameters after that.  All the examples I have seen assume the only parameter going to the second function will be the response from the first function.

```
var GetToken = function (username, password) {
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: webService + "ccGetToken",
    data: "{UserId: '" + username + "', UserPass: '" + password + "'}",
    dataType: "json"
});}

var SimpleQuery = function(token, docTypeID, aTypeID, Value){
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: webService + "ccSimpleQuery",
    data: "{UserToken: '" + token + "', DocTypeID: '" + docTypeID + "', AType: '" + aTypeID + "', ccAValue: '" + Value + "'}",
    dataType: "json"
});}
```

Something like this?

`$.when(GetToken("username", "password")).pipe(SimpleQuery(response.d, "DocTypeId", "ATypeId", "Value")).then(function(response){//do stuff here});`

Comment: As I read it, the only parameter you are going to pass from the call to ```GetToken``` to ```SimpleQuery``` is the token, right?